# Using Array in ng-model for a input of type number shows default value as 0

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an input box of type number in which i have used the ng-model which is an array when the array is empty the input shows the value as 0 but when i input a number the existing zero is not getting deleted and it shows the value with 0 as starting.

```
Eg:   Instead of 5 it shows as 05
```

Html:

```
<input stopccp decimalpoint
       type="number"
       placeholder="{{'ededuction_message' | translate}} - {{ vm.singleproduct.selectedtype === 'piece' ? 'Pec' : 'Kg' }}"
       ng-model="vm.total_amount[$index]"
       id="field2"
       >
```

Controller:

```
vm.total_amount = [];
```

how could i show only the value which i typed instead of showing the zero as prefix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use string replaces in onkeydown :

```
onkeydown="if(this.value.length !== 0) this.value = this.value.replace('0','');"
```

this one is replacing your all input 0 values

```
onkeydown="if(this.value.length !== 0) this.value = this.value.indexOf('0') == 0 ? this.value.substring(1) : this.value;"
```

this one is replacing your particular index value

Comment: let me check it

Answer (score 0):

You could also do it with:

```
onchange="this.value=this.value*1"
```

This will automatically convert the value entered into a number.